extracting strings of text with a pattern using VBA
I am trying to write a script in VBA that recovers from an MS Word document any text string starting with two capital letters, followed by four to fifteen numbers, ignoring spaces, "-", and "/". The maximum length of the text string is 18 characters.
I want the extracted numbers to print on another Word or Excel document as a list.
Typical strings can be "BN 123456" or "NH123456" or "ZB20458-9654", which will be listed as
"BN 123456"
"NH123456"
"ZB20458-9654"

Every time I run script in Word I get the message "No matches found". I think I have not been able to get the program to even reach the part where it searches the pattern
Sub RecoverText()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pattern As String
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim match As Variant
    
    ' Define the regex pattern to find strings starting with two capital letters, a space, and four to fifteen numbers
    pattern = "\b[A-Z]{2}\s\d{4,15}\b"
    
    ' Create a new document to store the recovered strings
    Set doc = Documents.Add
    
    ' Set the range to search the entire document
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    
    ' Find all matches using regex
    Set matches = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With matches
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .pattern = pattern
    End With
    
    ' Iterate through each match and add it to the new document
    For Each match In matches.Execute(rng.Text)
        ' Check if the length of the matched string is less than or equal to 18 characters
        If Len(match.Value) <= 18 Then
            doc.Content.InsertAfter match.Value & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next match
    
    ' Display the new document
    doc.Activate
    
    ' Notify user if no matches were found
    If matches.Execute(rng.Text).Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matches found."
    End If
End Sub


\s matches one whitespace, not any amount of whitespace or no whitespace. You are not doing anything to ignore the - and / either.

Thanks! would the following ignore - and ? "\b[A-Z]{2}[\s/-]*\d{4,15}\b"

d{4,15} doesn't account for cases like ZB20458-9654 (you'd only get ZB20458)

Something like "\b[A-Z]{2}[\s-/]*[\d-/]{4,15}\b" would allow for dashes and forward slashes in the numeric segment, but makes the length check more difficult - maybe re-run the regexp after removing spaces, dashes and slashes, and make sure it still passes?

Try this out:
Option Explicit

Sub RecoverText()
    Dim doc As Document, matches As Collection, m
    
    Set matches = AllMatches(ActiveDocument.Content)
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        Set doc = Documents.Add
        For Each m In matches
            doc.Content.InsertAfter m & vbCrLf
        Next m
    Else
        MsgBox "No matches found."
    End If
    
End Sub

'Return a collection of all matches for PATTERN in `txt`
Function AllMatches(txt As String) As Collection
    Const PATTERN As String = "\b[A-Z]{2}[\s-/]*[\d-/]{4,15}\b" 'allow for spaces, - and /
    Dim match As Variant
    
    Set AllMatches = New Collection
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .PATTERN = PATTERN
        For Each match In .Execute(txt)
            If Len(match.Value) <= 18 Then
                AllMatches.Add match.Value
            End If
        Next match
    End With
End Function


Hi, It was actually extremelly useful and works perfectly. Also, I find your suggestion much easier to understand. Thank you very much
